# Route in react Application is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to change the route of react application with react-router-dom

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/id" component={Random}/>
  <Route path="/" exact component={Products}/>
  
  </Switch>
```

Inside the application when I am using /id in the URL it is rendering Products Component instead of Random Component

Inside index.js the code is:

```html
ReactDOM.render(
 <BrowserRouter><Products/></BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be rendering your router. You are currently rendering the product component

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/id" component={Random}/>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Products}/> 
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should render the Switch component inside BrowserRouter tag.